# Incorrect date format generated in sink in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using the copy data utility in Azure Data Factory to copy data from a REST source to a CSV file. When I preview that source data in ADF the date format is the correct ISO format however when it is written to a csv file or a database table the format changes to something that looks a bit like a unix timestamp e.g. '/Date(340502400000)/'.

Source:
[Preview data from the source in ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcL46.png)

Destination:
[Actual data written to the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJrNN.png)

I've been trying to figure out how to change this to write the date to the file in the ISO format but I'm getting nowhere. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share some more details: the copy data activity and sink dataset settings; also the csv viewed in a text editor not Excel.

Comment: I've tried a few different options on the sink, I've tested both txt and csv files and also set up and configured a MySQL database as a sink destination. On all occasions the dates are output in the format /Date(xxx)/. I've tried setting up the copy data activity manually and via the copy data wizard, both lead to the same results. I've viewed the results in notepad and Excel and the date format stays the same.

Comment: Hi @RomanoPlescia, it's a little strange. I tested and it has no issue in my side. Please try my way and if it still doesn't work, I would suggest you ask Azure support for the deep helps. I'm afraid we can't explain that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I logged a call with Microsoft who initially didn't know how to resolve this issue either. Eventually it was escalated all the way up to the ADF product team (developers) who came back with a formula to use in a Data Flow.

What you have to do to convert the date format is to first use a Data Copy Task to dump the data into a "raw" dataset, then using a Data Flow Task you can transform the date values using a Derived Column. In the Derived column use the below formula to convert the JSON date format to an ISO date format, then write it to the destination dataset.

```
toTimestamp("1970-01-01 00:00:00") + seconds(toInteger((ltrim(rtrim([SourceColumn], "+0000)/"),"/Date("))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the same string date with your source and all works well in my side.
[image]

You could manually set the sink data type, like **String** or **Datatime**
[image]

Csv output(**Datetime**):
[image]

After doing these, if the issue still exist, the best way is that ask [Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for the deep helps. Only them can tell you what happened in your pipeline.

HTH.

Comment: @RomanoPlescia Sorry to hear that. Do you think about ask azure support?

Comment: I will raise a support ticket this morning, I will post the fix here once we get it sorted

Comment: Hi @RomanoPlescia, thanks for sharing the error message.  Can you use Data Flow?  what's the encoding of your csv file. If you can use Data Flow, please use derived column to build the expression to convert the date column.

Comment: @RomanoPlescia do you have any other concerns?  If my answer is helpful for you, hope  you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer but still no joy, all I get is a type conversion error.

*Error
Operation on target Copy_Lake_CSV failed: Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'lastModifiedDateTime' contains an invalid value '/Date(1615206773000+0000)/'. Cannot convert '/Date(1615206773000+0000)/' to type 'DateTime'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'*